# How can I avoid a delay when ng-class is applied to the body tag?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a class name on the `<body>` tag of a page to define whether the contents of a page is zoomed.

```
<body 'ng-class'=> "Preferences.zoomed()">
```

The default setting for `Preferences.zoomed()` is false and so the page loads in a non zoomed state.

Unfortunately though there seems to be a brief delay in between the page loading and `ng-class` getting evaluated. This means that when the page loads (and is set to zoom) it constantly (albeit briefly) flips from the non-zoomed state to the zoomed state making things flicker unpleasantly.

#### I presume this is because Angular evaluates after the dom loads...

I'm guessing that this momentary state occurs because the angular isn't parsed and evaluated until after the dom completes loading. Hence the page loads with `zoom=false` and then flicks to `zoom-true`.

#### How can I force ng-class to be evaluated as it loads into the page?

Is there any way to force Angular to evaluate this expression as the element itself loads and to avoid this flickering?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: @PeterNixey: No you can't make Angular evaluate before the DOM is loaded. If it is so important (and if `ngCloak` doesn't work for you) maybe you could use "vanilla JS". What is "Preferences.zoomed()" ? Where does it come from and when is it evaluated ?

Comment: Preferences.zoomed() is an accessor method on a Factory that stores the user's zoom preference for the page. You can see the effect of it here: http://brojure.com/brojure/tip-top-interior-design. There's a toggle in the top-right of the page that alters your zoom pref. ng-cloak actually seems to do the job although now there's a brief flash of no content ;) http://staging.brojure.com/brojure/greece-the-cyclades-islands. Ultimately I need to make the app a SPO but in the meantime ng-cloak seems to have done the jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

```
<body 'ng-class'=> "Preferences.zoomed()" ng-cloak="">
```

css:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```